# Installing Electrum on a cold wallet linux usb

Tags: electrum

I don't usually use linux but I'm looking to start using it more, if I can just figure out how to do anything. . .

I'm using Ubuntu on a usb, I've downloaded Electrum (from the site since I couldn't download python-pip or electrum through the terminal). So in the terminal I'm in the Electrum folder and trying to install electrum, but the message `Unable to locate package electrum`. I think I need to `enable the component called 'universe'` but I've had no luck with the [answers as depicted here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

If you can offer any advice as to how or why I couldn't originally install pip, or why electrum won't work now I could really use the help. I need to make this wallet, and I've been trying for a very long stupid time trying to, and I have btc idly sitting by that need to go into a wallet. Sorry for such a basic question, but I'm running out of time with this.

Answer (score 1):

For now you can use AppImage file from electrum.org website. Download AppImage to your Ubuntu USB, then:

```
$ chmod +x electrum-3.3.8-x86_64.AppImage
$ ./electrum-3.3.8-x86_64.AppImage
```